# Unsupported URL on ios 8

Tags: ios8, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to fetch a json from google places with the following code:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%i&types=%@&sensor=true&key=%@", center.latitude, center.longitude, rad, types, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];
NSLog(@"%@",query);
NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:query];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:googleRequestURL] queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching data: %@",[error description]);
    } else {
        //To-do
    }
}];
```

The resulting url is: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=37.337566,-122.041202&radius=1000&types=accounting|bowling_alley|doctor&sensor=true&key=MY_KEY

(my key is ommitted for obsious reasons)

Which works fine from my laptop's browser, but return the error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x7fe47bc138f0 {NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe47be9dbe0 "unsupported URL"}
```

I tried using http instead of https (in the browser it returns a json with some error message, but still returns something) with no success.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I got it resolved. Good Luck!

```
NSString *google = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=%f,%f&radius=500&types=%@&key=%@";  
NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:google, coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude, types, GOOGLE_KEY];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Comment: Thank you, the percents escapes part was sufficient!